# Publishing complete Play application to Nexus with publish?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I am using Play Framework and am trying to deploy a complete application to a repository on my Nexus.

The problem is that `play publish` is only publishing the pom file and the jar of my application but I want to put all jars on my nexus so that I can download the complete application from it and be able to start it from that point immediately.

How can I configure or change the `publish` command in Play?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is described in the official documentation of Play Framework in [Creating a standalone version of your application](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist):

> you sometimes need to build a binary version of your application and
>   deploy it to the server without any dependency on Play itself. You can
>   do this with the dist task.

and...

> This produces a ZIP file containing all JAR files needed to run your
>   application in the target/universal folder of your application.

Having the zip, you need to upload it to the repository.